# GET post and weird url value

Tags: php, url, get

I post a hidden field with every submit button using GET method.

```
  <?php
      if(isset($_GET["topic"]))
      {
          $topic=$_GET["topic"];
    ?>
       <input type="hidden" name="topic" value=<?php echo $topic; ?>/>
     <?php    
      }
    ?>
```

The problem is when I click the submit button and I get this / 'slash' in my url.

got topic cars/

(when printed with echo on the screen)

With every button press I get another slash..and my url comes to look like this..

```
http://localhost/IHow/home.php?searchEngine=&topic=cars%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F&page=0
```

How to prevent this from happening, cause I need the topic url variable for my mysql query..

Comment: Fyi, you need to use `htmlspecialchars()` on the value and quote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have quotes around the `value` attribute, and you also don't have a space between the attribute and the trailing slash.  The slash is considered to be a part of the `value` attribute, so it gets sent.  Add quotes, add a space, or do both.

As TheifMaster says, you should also use `htmlspecialchars()` on `topic`

Comment: Indeed. This will do the trick: `<input type="hidden" name="topic" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($topic); ?>"/>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
      if(isset($_GET["topic"]))
      {
          $topic=$_GET["topic"];
          if($topic[strlen($topic)-1] == '/')  //check if last char is '/'
          $topic = substr($topic,1,strlen($topic)-1); //$topic is $topic - last character
    ?>
       <input type="hidden" name="topic" value=<?php echo $topic; ?>/>
     <?php    
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: lol..too convoluted for a simple task. But thanks for the algorithm

Comment: algorithm ? what algorithm ? :-) Did i miss something ?